# Android JavaMail Detect If Server Goes Offline

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, imap

I'm currently developing an email application with a background service used in conjunction with the JavaMail Idle functionality. The background service keeps the idle functionality working by issuing a check every 29 minutes (as the server being used (Exchange server)) can sometimes drop the connection after 30 minutes of being connected.

Whilst this works perfectly, if the Exchange server is offline, then the application will continue to attempt to reconnect to the IMAP folder indefinately. I have noticed spikes in data usage between the hours of 3AM & 6AM (a typical Exchange update time).

To avoid the increased data usage, I am looking to implement functionality where the app should attempt to reconnect to the IMAP folder three times and then display a warning to the user that the server is offline and a new connection attempt will be retried in 30 minutes.

In order to achieve this, how would I be able to detect if the Exchange server is actually offline/updating & would any exceptions be thrown, if the app cannot connect to the IMAP folder? As if an exception would be thrown, then I could save a local int variable and increment it by one every time the exception is thrown and then show the alert to the user on the third time.

My current code implementation can be seen below:

```
public void checkInboxEmail(final String host, final String user, final String password) {

    Log.d(TAG, "checkEmail");

    this.host = host;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "checkEmail - run()");

                long databaseRecords;

                //create properties field
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
                properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
                properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

                emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                    }
                });


                IMAPStore imapStore = (IMAPStore) emailSession.getStore("imaps");
                // imapStore.connect();

                imapStore.connect(host, user, password);

                if (imapStore.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d("MailPush", "Successfully connected to IMAP");
                } else {
                    Log.d("MailPush", "Not connected to IMAP");
                }

                final IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) imapStore.getFolder("Inbox");
                folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_WRITE);

                databaseRecords = dbManager.getReceivedEmailRecordsCount();

                if (databaseRecords < folder.getMessageCount()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Receiving Mail...");
                    receiveMail(folder.getMessages());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Records match.");
                }

                Folder[] fdr = imapStore.getDefaultFolder().list();
                for (Folder fd : fdr)
                    System.out.println(">> " + fd.getName());

                folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {

                    public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {

                        System.out.println("Message Added Event Fired");
                        Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE TYPE: " + e.getType());
                        //ADDED = 1 & REMOVED = 2

                        try {
                            Message[] messages = e.getMessages();

                            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

                            for (Message message : messages) {
                                if (!message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {

                                    //Message is new (hasn't been seen) > Message Details
                                    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                                    System.out.println("Email Number " + (message.getMessageNumber()));
                                    System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                                    System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                                    System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

                                    String from = message.getFrom()[0].toString();

                                    String cc = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC));
                                    Log.d(TAG, "CC 1: " + cc);

                                    Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
                                    cc = InternetAddress.toString(recipients);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "CC 2: " + cc);

                                    //Check Encryption Details > Add SEEN Flag > Add to database
                                    checkEncryption((MimeMessage) message, from, cc);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Message Removed Event fired");
                    }
                });

                folder.addMessageChangedListener(new MessageChangedListener() {

                    public void messageChanged(MessageChangedEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Message Changed Event fired");
                    }
                });

                startListening(folder);

                //close the store and folder objects
                //   emailFolder.close(false);
                //   store.close();

            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void startListening(IMAPFolder imapFolder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startListening");

    // We need to create a new thread to keep alive the connection
    Thread t = new Thread(
            new KeepAliveRunnable(imapFolder), "IdleConnectionKeepAlive"
    );

    t.start();

    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting IDLE");
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting IDLE");
            imapFolder.idle();
        } catch (FolderClosedException fex) {
            //Server closes connection.
            Log.d(TAG, "FolderClosedException. Server potentially dropped connection. Retrying connection...");
            fex.printStackTrace();

            if (!isServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service isn't running. Starting service...");

                //Start service
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra("host", host);
                intent.putExtra("email", user);
                intent.putExtra("password", password);

                context.startService(intent);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service is already running. Checking email...");
                checkInboxEmail(host, user, password);
            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            //Idle isn't supported by server.
            Log.d(TAG, "Messaging exception during IDLE: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Shutdown keep alive thread
    if (t.isAlive()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Interrupting thread");
        t.interrupt();
    }
}

private static class KeepAliveRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private static final long KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ = 60000 * 29; // 29 minutes (Exchange connection drops after 20-30 minutes)

    private IMAPFolder folder;

    KeepAliveRunnable(IMAPFolder folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ);

                // Perform a messageCount check just to keep alive the connection
                Log.d(TAG, "Performing a messageCount check to keep the connection alive");
                folder.getMessageCount();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignore, just aborting the thread...
                Log.d(TAG, "Interrupted...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // Shouldn't really happen...
                Log.d(TAG, "Unexpected exception while keeping alive the IDLE connection");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void receiveMail(Message[] messages) {
    try {

        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (Message message : messages) {
            if (!message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {

                //Message is new (hasn't been seen) > Message Details
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (message.getMessageNumber()));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

                String from = message.getFrom()[0].toString();
                String cc = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC));

                //Check Encryption Details > Add SEEN Flag > Add to database
                checkEncryption((MimeMessage) message, from, cc);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the server is up but not accepting connections, the connect will fail immediately (with an exception).  If the server is down, and you've set a connect timeout, the connect will fail after the timeout (with an exception).

Comment: Which exceptions will these be?

Comment: MessagingException, possibly some subclass such as com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @BillShannon's answer, if the server *host* is up but Exchange is not accepting connections, the connect will fail immediately with a `ConnectException: connection refused`. If the server host is down, the connect will fail after the timeout with a `ConnectException: connect timeout` (or possibly a `SocketTimeoutException`), *regardless* of whether you've set a connect timeout, as the platform always has one.

Comment: @BillShannon, I have added a MessagingException as a catch for my 'checkInboxEmail' function so then an alert is shown to the user (after the exception has been caught three times) but how can I stop JavaMail trying to reconnect? Would this just be through the use of the different timeouts and then use a handler to postDelay running the function until 30 minutes away from the current time?